# Django adds "index" to empty url

Tags: python, django

I am just learning Django. I can't understand why "index" is being added to the empty URL. I need the address to be http://127.0.0.1:8000/, but in the address bar it immediately changes to http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/.
However, if I enter http: // localhost: 8000 / there are no such problems.

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import include
from about import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('about.urls')),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

about app urls

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'), 
]
```

Comment: Share your `urls.py`...

Comment: please format your question per community standards: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: added urls.py to description

Comment: show your `about` app urls

Comment: added about app urls

Comment: I think it's because you don't have a slash for your index page. If you go to `http://localhost:8000` without a slash, it might work. But if you add a slash in your app url for index, you should be able to go to `http://localhost:8000/`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very simple, it was necessary to clear the browser cache :)

Comment: That solution doesn't work for me. It is not clear whether the issue lies with Django or my browser (Brave on Mac), but when I try to navigate to "localhost:8000", the browser goes to "localhost:8000/catalog", and there is no way I can get to the root localhost. Clearing the cache, deleting history had no effect. I have since moved to Firefox while waiting to figure out a solution.